# reactive extension for f#

Tags: visual-studio, f#, system.reactive

I am trying to call the rx 2.0 frameworok from fsharp.
I saw there is a project [FSharp.Reactive](https://github.com/panesofglass/FSharp.Reactive) which tries to map rx2.0 to FSharp.

Something very strange happens when I try to use it:

- There is an error shown in the IDE, which can be reproduced in the following code:

  ```
  module FSharp.Reactive2

  open System
  open System.Reactive
  open System.Reactive.Linq
  open System.Reactive.Concurrency

  type IObservable<'a> with
    // Subscribes to the Observable with just a next-function.
    member this.Subscribe(onNext:'a -> unit) =
      let toto = (Action<_> onNext)
      this.Subscribe(toto)
  ```

  > internal error : the list had different lengths. Parameter name `xs2`
- But when I compile it, it produces a dll, and the error goes away.  If I modify the code file again, the error reappears.

This happens in other projects using the System.Reactive dll.
Am I doing something wrong // is there anything to deal with it // is that a bug ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internal errors indicate compiler bugs.  Try sending an email to fsbugs@microsoft.com.

Comment: Yes, we already know about this issue, it will be fixed in the next release

Comment: Good catch. I have [a few tests](https://github.com/panesofglass/FSharp.Reactive/blob/master/tests/ObservableSpecs.fs#L84) -- and need a lot more -- that use that overload, but the test passed when I last ran it.